# Javascript: continue script after loading a new page

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code:

```js
const changeSelected = (e) => {
        let opcion = document.querySelector('.valor').value;
        window.App2.Storage.setItem("key", opcion);
        window.location.assign("/register"); // this load new route ...  (load fine but no values) 
        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
                let valor =  window.App2.Storage.getItem("key");
                const select = document.querySelector('#plan');
                // select.value = valor.value; 
                console.log(valor);
        }, false);
};
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', changeSelected);
```

I modified to `window.load` and no changes, in the same page, I can load values, but when try to load  the route (register), I search many answer here but no one is work.

Comment: Please do not undo corrected formatting and grammar fixes.

Comment: When you load a new page, everything from the old `window` context is destroyed.

Comment: Then submit a "form" is needed? thanks in advance....